Making Katexmathview to work in Androidstudio
Developing an app in Java that uses mathexpressions. Trying to make it work with Katexmathview. I am using the latest Androidstudio. It is not working by adding
implementation 'in.hourglass.mathrender:katexmathview:1.0.3' 

to the build.gradle file.
So I have downloaded the git-files (https://github.com/lingarajsankaravelu/Katex)and imported the files as a module and added the module as a dependency to the project.
When I build the project I get the following error:
ERROR: C:\Users\Reza\AndroidStudioProjects\MathTest\katexmathview\build\intermediates\incremental\debugAndroidTest\mergeDebugAndroidTestResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:865: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/preserveIconSpacing is private.
I tried to delete the row 865 in that file, but it seems that the file (values.xml) is generated at run-time and even if I delete the whole file, it becomes generated as a new file at run-time.
How to make it work?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The linked project is 4-7 years old. The first blocker will be the used Java version. Older Android projects can only be built using Java 8, newer require java 11 or 17. Android Studio uses by default Java 17, so you have to manually change the Java run-time used by gradle in AS settings.

How to exactly change the Java run-time used by gradle in AS? I changed File->settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build tools->Gradle->Gradle JDK to java 1.8  ------------now the following errror:  "Gradle JVM version incompatible.
This project is configured to use an older Gradle JVM that supports up to version 8 but the current AGP requires a Gradle JVM that supports version 17."
